# not able to convert json string into c# object , getting error- because the type requires a JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list

i want to convert json data into c#, im getting error in converting json string into C# object.

Code

```
   List<Root> list = new List<Root>();
        list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(jsonString);
```

json data

```
    {
        "Set1": [
            {
                "TotalColumns": "5",
            "Header": "Date",
            "DataType": "DateTime",
            "MaxLength": "8"
        },
        {
            "TotalColumns": "5",
            "Header": "Code",
            "DataType": "Int",
            "MaxLength": "6"
        },
        {
            "TotalColumns": "5",
            "Header": "Description",
            "DataType": "String",
            "MaxLength": "500"
        },
        {
            "TotalColumns": "5",
            "Header": "Qty",
            "DataType": "Int",
            "MaxLength": "6"
        },
        {
            "TotalColumns": "5",
            "Header": "Amount",
            "DataType": "Double",
            "MaxLength": "100"
        }
    ]
}
```

C# Class

```
public class Set1
    {
        public string TotalColumns { get; set; }
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public string MaxLength { get; set; }
    }

public class Root
{
    public List<Set1> Set1 { get; set; }
}
```

error

> deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[....Root]' because the type
> requires a JSON array

Comment: you shouldn't copy code if you do not understand ... especially if it's intended to work with json array and you wana work with json object ... asked multiple times already - use internet search

Comment: `var setOnes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString).Set1`?

Comment: The Json is not representing an array. It is a single object which has Set1 property which is a list. So you should try to deserialize it to a single Root object by doing `var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 variants

1. Get  a root object

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

2. Get a list

```
 List<Set1> Set1 = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["Set1"].ToObject<List<Set1>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually trying to cast the JSON as a `List<Root>`, but the JSON doesn't contain an array of the `Root` class.

What you could do is to deserialize your JSON as a `Root` instance instead of a `List<Root>`, but if you absolutely want to deserialize it into a `List<Root>`, your problem is in the code that generated the JSON, it doesn't serialized a `List` but a single instance of `Root`.